# Same binary on raspberry pi 2 and 3?

Tags: raspberry-pi3, raspberry-pi2

I'm building an app on a raspberry pi 3. I'm using Qt. 
Will the generated binary work on raspberry pi 2?

Thanks

Comment: Kinda depends on what the binary does.  If it uses a feature available only on the 3, I would guess it would fail when it tries.  I don't think your question is answerable beyond that.

Comment: Your question might be better suited over at https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/